# Javascript convert Object with child-objects into Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an Object which contains sub-objects as children. 
I need to convert it into array:

```
var myObj = {
    a: 5,
    b: 6,
    c: {
        a: {
            a: {
                a: 7
            }
        }
    },
    d: {
        a: {
            a: 8,
            b: 9,
            c: {
                a: 10
            }
        },
        b: 11
    }
}
```

**like this:**

```
myArray = [
    a: 5,
    b: 6,
    c: [
      a: [
        a: [
          a: 7
        ]
      ]
    ],
    d: [
      a: [
        a: 8,
        b: 9,
        c: [
          a: 10
        ]
      ],
      b: 11
    ]
  ];
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: While arrays can have properties (they are objects after all), why would you do it this way? And if you do want to do this, hint: Recursion

Comment: arrays may only have numeric keys; your desired "array" is not possible in javascript

Comment: Why do you need this? Sound like a classic XY problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/162238

Comment: because I need an array object to call it like `myArray[c][a][a][a]`

Comment: @jbabey arrays are objects in JS as well, so they can have non-numeric properties as well

Comment: @zur4ik have you tried calling it like that without first changing it to array?

Comment: @zur4ik that will work with an object: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/qLj7y/ There is no need to convert it to an array simply for that purpose

Comment: @zur4ik "because I need an array object to call it like myArray[c][a][a][a]" No, you don't; the square bracket notation works for accessing properties of objects as well. However, you need to pass them as strings (rather than trying to use them as the values of variables), so: `myObj["c"]["a"]["a"]["a"]`

Comment: @Tibos you mean to call like myObj[c][a][a][a] ?

Comment: Yess! now I see, so I can call Object variable with brackets also.
Thank you @AnthonyGrist

Comment: Objects take integers (coerced to strings) or strings as properties. You can use variables to access properties with matching keys as well

Comment: @AnthonyGrist please add you comment as "Answer" and I'll accept it. Thank you!

Comment: @zur4ik Tibos covered it all really well in his answer, so accept that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in your comments, it looks like you have an XY problem. You want X, but ask us for Y instead thinking it will help you, but in fact Y is much more difficult to solve than X.

There are two ways to access properties of an object in JavaScript:

- `obj.prop`
- `obj['prop']`

The difference between the two ways of accessing is that the second is more versatile, you can use some restricted keywords as property names, you can use variables to access the values, etc.

To access your nested property you can do (any option is fine):

- `myObj.c.a.a.a`
- `myObj['c']['a']['a']['a']`

You can even mix them: `myObj.c['a'].a['a']`, though it is probably more confusing, so you should avoid it.

Arrays in JS are also objects, that have some more functionality which deals with the properties with numeric names. It doesn't seem like you need any of those functionalities so you probably don't need an array.